# Is there a way to make a for loop with two parallel iterators in Scala?

Tags: scala, for-loop, foreach, syntax, iteration

I am trying to do a for loop on a `HashMap` in Scala, but I also need a count of my iteration, like an index of sorts. Here is what I want the functionality to be:

```
    val map = HashMap()
    val i = 0;

    for ((k, v) <- map) {
        // do something
        i += 1
    }
```

But I want it to look something like this, where i is updated inside the for loop syntax. But, this seems to act as a nested loop rather than a parallel iterator.

```
    for ((k, v) <- map; i <- 0 until map.size) {
        // do something
    }
```

Comment: You can `for (((k, v), i) <- map.zipWithIndex) {`

Comment: I think it's worth making this an answer. ;)

Comment: I would avoid for loops in Scala. They're not very functional, and Scala provides `map`, `flatMap`, and `foreach` methods on most collections so that you don't need to write the boilerplate of a for loop. It's much easier to write `collection.foreach(println)` than a for loop that does that same thing.

Comment: @csjacobs24Scala doesn't have for loops! Although for comprehensions look similar on the surface, it all desugars into `map`, `flatMap`, and `filter`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `zipWithIndex` method is designed specifically for this purpose:

```
for {((k, v), i) <- map.zipWithIndex} yield {???}
```

or

```
map.zipWithIndex.collect { case ((k, v), i) => ??? }
```

Personally I would use the second version in this case and only use the `for` syntax when iterating over multiple collections.